# building asp .net core 2.1 angular in Azure Devops with custom build configuration

Tags: azure-devops, asp.net-core-2.0

I created an asp.net core 2.1 angular application. In VSTS, I created the build with template asp.net core. It has the following steps `Restore`, `build`, `Test`, `Publish`, and `Publish Artifact`. During the Publish phase it runs it runs `ng build "--prod"`. 
On looking into `Myproject.csproj` I see there is reference to run npm build

```
Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --prod" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build:ssr -- --prod" Condition=" '$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true' " />
```

I would like to create different build `ng build --configuration=dev "--prod"` where I want to have different configuration for each build based on environment. In my `package.json` I have

```
"build:qa": "ng build --configuration=qa",
"build:prod": "ng build --configuration=prod",
```

How to I tie in all so that I can specify in the Azure Devops/VSTS step which configuration to use.

Comment: How did you manage to resolve this?